# Upgrade gnome-shell in ubuntu12.04

Tags: gnome

I have gnome-shell version 3.4 installed in my Ubuntu 12.04.  I want to upgrade it to the latest and stable version of gnome-shell (I mean a version after 3.4).

What should I do to update it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

That should do it.