# How to update the Gnome Shell version to the latest on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: gnome-shell

Recently I have noticed that gnome-shell version has new release 3.36.4 via below links..
https://phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=GNOME-3.36.4-Released
https://www.linuxcompatible.org/story/gnome-3364-released/

I have tried to upgrade to the new release 3.36.4 with below links or similar ones..
[How to update gnome-shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/690912/how-to-update-gnome-shell)
[How to upgrade to the latest GNOME version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/625244/how-to-upgrade-to-the-latest-gnome-version)
[Upgrade gnome-shell in ubuntu12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/347951/upgrade-gnome-shell-in-ubuntu12-04)

seems the links are older..

with `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade` I am only upgraded to 3.36.3 from 3.36.2

Assuming I have a testing system running Ubuntu 20.04, What is the step by step procedure to install 3.36.4 for testing purpose..

Comment: Assuming you're not going to answer your own question, why not just use *groovy* as you'll be using non-*focal* packages anyway, and you'll no longer have a pure support-LTS system (ie. `ubuntu-security-status` or `ubuntu-support-status` will report packages with shorter lives). You've mentioned a *testing system*...    Groovy currently has 3.36.3 my system reports, but it'll move to 3.36.4 I suspect very soon...

Comment: @guiverc thanks for commenting.. thing is that when it is available to public.. what is the point not able to install it? there must be a way to install it when it is available and I am really willing to install it/ test it.

Comment: I tried in Ubuntu 20.10 too.. it is 3.36.2 out of the box and after several workarounds it went to 3.36.3 but not 3.36.4 tried some other linux distros hoping I would get 3.36.4 but I could not manage.. trying since 36hrs.. breaking head..

Comment: My installed *groovy* system reports 3.36.3 (at least that's what I got from `gnome-shell --version` as I don't use GNOME very often..), but yeah it's not .4   I don't monitor GNOME (*not my cup of tea*) so you'll have to wait for others sorry.  I thought I read details on the weekend, but I didn't really take notice sorry (I'll return if something comes to me).

Comment: Short of someone packaging it in a repository, you always can compile it yourself. Jokes aside, I would recommend you just install an arch based system to easily have the latest Gnome Shell for testing. Anyway, I think this dot version will make it in Ubuntu after some time. We are now at 3.36.3. Activating the "proposed" repository will make updates land sooner into your test system.

Comment: @vanadium thanks for the comment.. Yes I did install manjaro suggested by manjaro user n followed his instructions.. now I have 3.36.4 and my job for testing one feature is solved..

Comment: So I added it as a answer. Disappointing it may be, but I think that apart from compiling yourself, enabling proposed will be the fastest option to have it, not when you want but when the Canonical developpers are ready (maybe it is there already).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Comment: @N0rbert nice info.. I think it will answer if I edit the Question.. does the above link mean manually installing gnome-shell is not possible? my Question is about step by step procedure to manually install once the gnome says its out to public as in two links at start of the Question..

Comment: Theoretically we can compile any software with almost any version. There is no specifics here. You start with getting build-dependencies and then create debs on your local machine. Personally I think that this it is a not good entertainment as it is time-consuming procedure. And It will not make GNOME Shell better.

Comment: yesterday I tried compiling and I broke the system.. reinstalled Ubuntu.. as I clearly indicated that I would like to test it and I really consumed a lot of time ofcourse around 36hrs.. I was looking for a step by step procedure on how to do that.. my question still stands though I installed manjaro n using 3.36.4

Answer (score 2):

Minor dot versions of Gnome Shell likely will make it in your Ubuntu installation at some point. To have faster upgrades with packages that are being tested before release, you may want - on your test system - to enable the "proposed" PPA.

1. Launch "Software and Updates"
2. On the "Developpers" tab, check "Pre-release updates (focal-proposed)
3. Close the dialog: the software sources will update.

Read more about "Proposed", including ways to not have everything updated automatically from "Proposed": **strong text**

I am afraid that your other options are limited. One can always install by compiling, but that is a daunting task requiring good technical system skills.

Comment: I did all the steps you mentioned. this method needs to wait until Ubuntu triggers the upgrade.. my Question is when it is available to public what is the step by step procedure to upgrade it.. Thanks!!!

Comment: As I indicated: compiling yourself probably. Hopefully someone else comes around who can write the procedure out, so you can accept that answer ;-)

Comment: yes exactly @vanadium..Thank You for your all time support..

Comment: This worked for me. After the above steps I additionally ran `sudo apt install gnome-shell` and got the updated version. Thanks @vanadium